# Connecting DC Remote HyperV server in c#

Tags: wmi, hyper-v, domaincontroller

I am trying to connect a hyperV server remotely which is the part of same Domain Controller as the local system is. It works if I give username without AD, but fails every time(with error "invalid parameter") when username is with AD.e.g. AD\administrator.
// This works

```
 Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
 Authority = "ntlmdomain:" + _domain;
 options.Username = "administrator";
 options.Password = _authPas;
```

//But this doesn't work

```
 Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
 Authority = "ntlmdomain:" + _domain;
 options.Username = "testAD\\administrator";
 options.Password = _authPas;
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Note: Hyper-V server(remote) and and local server are both part of same domain. I am able to connect with local administrator of the remote server. But not with domain administrator. Even if I dont use dominname in username for domain Administrator, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are giving the Domain name in username after you provided the domain name in "Authority"

Already the Domain is mentioned in Authority so the the username should be only Username without domainname

Giving multiple times will not work

Comment: Note: Hyper-V server(remote) and and local server are both part of same domain. I am able to connect with local administrator of the remote server. But not with domain administrator. Even if I dont use dominname in username for domain Administrator, it doesn't work.

Comment: are you sending domain name for the "Authority" check that.  As per my view there is only problem with sending the information check that first